# I can't get the contents of a container <div> to center properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

The code is in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r8ND3/1/. I cannot figure out how to center the div "#game" and its contents. I have tried using `margin: 0 auto;`, `float:center;`, and even `$("game").css("margin-left", .5*$(window).width()-.5*$("#game").width())` inside of `$(document).ready()`, but none have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put a `width` on `#game` and use `margin: 0 auto` since you can't center something that's 100% width.

```
#game {
  width: 270px; 
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Most of these answers are pretty good, choosing this because it has the correct width and explains the solution.

Comment: +1 for explanation but I'd avoid hardcoding widths whenever possible.

Comment: @cbayram In the context of this question, each "box" in the grid of divs making up #game has a width of 25 and border of one on each side according to the CSS. The Javascript fills each "row" with 10 of these, meaning the width will always be 270px.

Answer (score 0):

```
#game {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#game  {
  width: 275px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```